# map with splice within another map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping, slice

I'm trying to make a map within another map, however it seems to be the opposite of what I'm asking. I would like to imitate each map next to each other, for example:

```
A = B
A.1 = B.1
A.2 = B.2
```

and so one, however, instead I'm getting

```
A = B 
A = B.1 
A = B.2
A.1 = B
A.1 = B.1
A.1 = B.2
```

And so on.. Here is my code:

```
  {titles.map((t, index) => (
    <tr>
      {console.log(this.state)}
      <td key={index}>{t.toString() + " : "}</td>
      <td>{this.state.files.map((x, index) => (
            <div key={index} style={{color:'#01579b', cursor: 'pointer', border: '1px ridge'}} 
              key={`link${index}`} 
              onClick={this.downloadFile.bind(null,x)}>{x.original_name}
            </div>                   
            ))}
      </td>   
    </tr>
  ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{titles.map((t, index) => (
    <tr>
      {console.log(this.state)}
      <td key={index}>{t.toString() + " : "}</td>
      <td>
         <div key={index} style={{color:'#01579b', cursor: 'pointer', border: '1px ridge'}} key={`link${index}`} 
          onClick={this.downloadFile.bind(null,this.state.files[index])}>
          {this.state.files[index].original_name}
        </div>                       
      </td>   
    </tr>
  ))}
```

in above code block we are doing this.state.files[index] i.e when in map we are at index 0 -> A, this.state.files[0] -> B

when in map we are at index 1 -> A.1, this.state.files[1] -> B.1
and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but then it tells me "Cannot read property 'original_name' of undefined".

Comment: can you check what result are you getting for  ```this.state.files[index] ```  ?

Comment: surprisingly, the results are going through in cosole.log. All of them have original_name inside, I don't understand where is the undefiend coming from.

Comment: the number of items in A and B are of same length or different? there might be chance that B i.e state.files has less items than titles hence it is throwing error

Comment: I think it's throwing error, because it's rendering when things are closed. Let me change to make it render only if something is being displayed and I will update you if it works!